# List wtih Python

Tags: python, lis

I have next code:

```
listTest = ["ration","hello","exclamation"]

word=['masha[a-z]*']
channels=['BOOMERANG','NICK']

targets=['KIDS','BOYS']
l=[]
for j in range(22):                                                         
    df=fran_tvp[fran_tvp.Año.isin([año]) & fran_tvp.Channel.isin(channels)&fran_tvp.Week.isin([j])]  
    l.append(df[['TimeBand',targets]].set_index('TimeBand').rename(columns={'TimeBand' : 'TimeBand' + 
    str(j)}))

df=pd.concat((l),axis=1).reset_index()
df=df.iloc[:, [0,6,10,14,19,21]]

df.columns = [' ','20-ene','20-feb','20-mar','20-abr','20-may']
```

The problem is that with the lists it does not make me search for targets, is there any function to use with the lists? 
Since if I use  targets = 'KIDS' it works.

Comment: You code has no indentation. The code under the for loop should be indented (at least the first line). Please fix that and retry.

Comment: I already corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need add to list.

**Ex:**

```
l.append(df[['TimeBand'] + targets].set_index('TimeBand').rename(columns={'TimeBand' : 'TimeBand' + str(j)}))
```

Comment: it worked for me but I throw the error "ValueError: the form of the passed values ​​is (8, 44), the indices imply (4, 44),apparently it is for the concat